# Why not PDO_MySQL return integer?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm migrating my PHP codes from `mysql` (deprecated in 5.5) to `PDO_MySQL`. However, `mysql_fetch_row` returns integer while `PDOStatement::fetch` returns strings for numbers. How can I make PDO behaves like the former one?

Result of `mysql_fetch_row`:

```
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Result of `PDOStatement::fetch`:

```
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to false, if you really need it with loosely-typed PHP

If `mysql_fetch_row` returns you int for SUM either (I never cared to check) - then it does some magic like `if (ctype_digit($val)) $row[$key] = (int)$val;` - so you can do in your DBAL

As far as I understand the way prepared statements works, it uses the same packet structure for either sending and retrieving data, and this packet contains data type.

It looks like that server can return data in 2 formats - native and mysqlnd, depends on the request type. A latter one can be interpreted by client library to cast resulting value.

Comment: It works in most cases, but doesn't work for `SELECT SUM(...`. Also, as its name indicates, will advantages of prepared statements be invalid with this option?

Comment: To whoever reads this answer in the future: 1) Nope, he didn't misread the question. 2) Yes, it actually changes the data type of returned values.

Comment: @Haocheng Read this sentence carefully, it's double negative ;)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks, and I'm curious about why this option has effect on this behavior, and I think it's undocumented in php.net.

Comment: I've checked that `mysql` returns string on `SUM(..` as well.

Comment: While this option does the trick, it’s actually intended for something else. Changing the preferred mode for prepared statements might cause undesired effects. Since it’ll [fall back to supported driver behavior](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.setattribute.php), it’s no guarantee as well. I wonder if there’s some other sleek way, like `PDO::NUMERIC_STRING_TO_INT`.

Answer (score 14):

For the records, PDO provides a feature that would alter this, `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES`:

> Convert numeric values to strings when fetching. Requires `bool`.

The rationale behind the setting is that database engines can handle very large numbers (Oracle, for instance, allows 38-digit numbers) and PHP cannot. Retrieving those numbers as strings is a method to keep safe and prevent data loss.

Unluckily, [the MySQL driver does not support it](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44341):

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'test', 'test');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
$sql = 'SELECT 1 AS integer_number, 3.14 AS floating_point';
$res = $pdo->query($sql);
while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

```
array(2) {
  ["integer_number"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["floating_point"]=>
  string(4) "3.14"
}
```

Comment: I like the rationale part of the answer, though if I have seen correctly in-use, the MySQL PDO doesn't support `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES`, as _everything_ is returned as a `string` data-type already, meaning this `attribute` is fairly useless with that driver.

Comment: @Jon - You are right, I've just found it myself. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use json_encode and json_decode with JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK option to retrieve your array with numeric types:

```
$my_array = json_decode(json_encode( $my_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ));
```

Comment: The issue with JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK is that other text could be numeric, e.g. user-generated content. Seemingly random fields becoming numbers might be a problem.