# MeekroDB and PDO query return associative array with ONLY strings

Tags: php, pdo, meekro

I have the following code on a PHP script:

```
$DB = new MeekroDB($host, $user, $pass, $dbIntra, $port, $encoding);    
$DB->throw_exception_on_error = true;
$DB->error_handler = false;
$DB->throw_exception_on_nonsql_error = true;

$result = $DB->query("SELECT usr_id, usr_username, usr_blocked, usr_language, usr_nickname, entc_id FROM usuario LIMIT 1");

var_dump($result);
```

Resulting in the following:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["usr_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["usr_username"]=>
    string(12) "igor@ppp.com"
    ["usr_blocked"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["usr_language"]=>
    string(2) "ES"
    ["usr_nickname"]=>
    string(5) "Ivan1"
    ["entc_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to have MeekroDB respect the datatypes assigned in the database model?

**UPDATE**

Also tried with PDO with the same result, it seems it is not MeekroDB but PHP:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=...;dbname=...', $user, $pass); 
$query="SELECT usr_id, usr_username, usr_blocked, usr_language, usr_nickname, entc_id FROM usuario LIMIT 1";
$data = $dbh->query($query);
$result = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($result);
```

**UPDATE**

I would expect something like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["usr_id"]=>
    int(1) 1                          // Notice int
    ["usr_username"]=>
    string(12) "igor@ppp.com"
    ["usr_blocked"]=>
    int(1) 0                          // Notice int
    ["usr_language"]=>
    string(2) "ES"
    ["usr_nickname"]=>
    string(5) "Ivan1"
    ["entc_id"]=>
    int(1) 1                          // Notice int
  }
}
```

The associative array should have the same datatype defined in the database.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what result do you expect?

Comment: @jaro1989 The associative array should have the same datatype defined in the database. (updated question)

Comment: so.. it's a duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129432/why-not-pdo-mysql-return-integer

Comment: wasn't really a duplicate since originally asked for MeekroDB (uses mysqli behind the scenes)... later tried with PDO... but thanks for the feedback

Comment: and here's for mysqli: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php. MeekroDB is just a little upgrade over mysqli and nothing more. I'd better not use such (bad written btw) approaches. But it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Meekro you cannot get typed results, as it is not using prepared statements - the only way to get the data type right off the fetch.

With PDO, it is possible only [if PDO is built upon **mysqlnd** and emulation mode is turned **off**](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#returntypes). Having there prerequisites, you can have your results already in corresponding types